# Произношение испанских слов с удвоенной L

Tags: заимствования, удвоенные-буквы

В испанском языке удвоенное L читается как Й: Mallorca - Майорка, paella - паэйя и т.д. Так вот, об этой самой паэйе (это блюда испанской кухни - нечто вроде рагу одновременно с мясом и морепродуктами). Везде, на всех ценниках в магазинах и во всех рецептах написано "паэлья", но у меня, как у человека, изучавшего испанский, язык не поворачивается говорить неправильно. Собственно, дело не только в этом блюде, просто, это первый пример, который пришел в голову, а подобных слов довольно много.
Что вы посоветуете: говорить так, как подобные слова звучат по-испански, или все-таки через Л?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указанную Вами особенность фонетики испанского языка знают лишь те, кто изучал этот язык, поэтому,думаю,вполне оправданна тенденция приспосабливать звучание заимствованных слов к особенностям языка-заимствователя. В этом отношении показателен искусственный язык эсперанто, где произносится каждая написанная буква.

Answer (score 2):

В разных диалектах ll произносится по-разному (в Южной Америке бывает и вовсе почти [дж]). Книжки, по которой я начинала учиться, у меня под рукой сейчас нет, но там чуть ли не кастильскому произношению (считающемуся классическим) приписывали вариант, близкий к [л'j]. Да даже и йот получается не такой, как наш. При обрусении иностранных слов частенько действует правило "так сложилось исторически" -- ну вот есть слова, в которых передают ll как "ль". С городом Севильей, например, то же самое. Считайте, что произносите не испанское слово, а русское, которым переводится испанское paella. (Фактически, так оно и есть.) <s>И скажите спасибо, что не "лл".</s> В крайнем случае можно покупать это чудесное блюдо в супермаркетах, где нет необходимости называть его вслух:)

Answer (score 1):

я живу в Испании 22,5 года, две буквы ll, 100% нужно в Испании произносить как букву " й". В странах Латинской Америки можно встретить произношение как " ль". паэлья и паэйя.В Испании паэйя, в других странах может быть и паэлья.